# Linear Algebra. Solution help.

Tags: linear-algebra

1) Let $P_n$ be the set of polynomials up to the $n$-th degree.

Show that $P_n$ is a subspace of the linear space $\def\R{\mathbb{R}}F(\R,\R) = \{ f \mid f : \R \to \R \}$ where $f$ is a function.

Solution: To show that $P_n$ is a subspace of $F$...

i: the set is non empty, which is true, ii: that additive closure property holds...

Here I get stuck because complex numbers are part of $P_n$, and therefore this property does not hold? Same problem with the Scalar closure property.

2) Let $B = \{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots,x^n\}$

Show that $B$ is a basis for $P_n$

Solution: $B$ is a basis if it is linearly independent, and it spans $P_n$.

i: $B$ is linearly independent, because the equation $a_11+a_2x+a_3x^2+a_nx^n = 0$
has a trivial relationship $a_i = 0$

ii: $B$ spans $P_n$, because all of the roots of $n$ degree polynomials are in $B$

Comment: It seems reasonable to assume that the polynomials have real coefficients. Otherwise the set of polynomials is not even a subset of $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding about functions here. A function can be defined on a set, with values in another set without hitting every value in its codomain. That is I can have a function
$$
f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}
$$
but it needs not be true that $\forall \; r \in \mathbb{R} \; \exists \; x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = r$. If the function has this property then it is called surjective, but there are functions which do not have this property. For example
$$
f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \; x \mapsto e^x
$$
is not a surjective function, but it is part of $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

Now to prove that, given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $P_n$ is a subspace of $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, presumably we're considering polynomials defined as such:
$$
p \in P_n \iff p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \partial(p) = n
$$
where $\partial(\cdot)$ stands for *degree of*. Just because some of these polynomials will not have *roots* in the real numbers here, does not mean they aren't validly defined as functions defined from $\mathbb{R}$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now given you understand the above, for $(1)$ we can see that for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0, q(x) = b_nx^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + b_0 \in P_n$ we have that
$$
p(x) + q(x) = (a_n + b_n)x^n +(a_{n-1} + b_{n-1})x^{n-1} + \cdots + (a_0 + b_0) \in P_n
$$
and likewise the scalar closure property holds as well (as long as your underlying scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$, which I'm guessing it is).

Now for part $(2)$ we can indeed see easily that $\{1,x,\ldots,x^n\}$ is linearly independent since the only way to make
$$
a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n = 0
$$
true is by setting $a_i = 0$ for every $i$. This might need some justification; one way to justify this is by saying the only way for this to be linearly dependent is by the coefficients being functions of $x$ themselves.

Your justification for why $\{1,x,\ldots,x^n\}$ spans $P_n$ doesn't really make sense. In order for a set $B$ to span another set $V$, we must have that for every $v \in V \; \exists \{a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ s.t.
$$
a_0b_0 + a_1b_1 + \cdots + a_nb_n = p
$$
where $b_i$ are elements of $B$. With this said we need to show that every $p(x) \in P_n$ there exists a set of coefficients $\{a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ whereas
$$
a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n = p(x)
$$
Now this is easily seen since every element $p(x) \in P_n$ is of the form
$$
p(x) = b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_nx^n
$$
so we can take $a_i = b_i$ for every $i$, so that we have shown that $\{1,x,\ldots,x^n\}$ indeed spans $P_n$.

Hopefully this provides clarification!